# PHP Symfony- How to inherit multiple classes from one php file

Tags: php, symfony, classnotfoundexception, fatal-error

I am using Symfony 2.4

I have a PHP file OAuth.php which has multiple classes inside that.

Code of OAuth.php is as below

```
<?php

namespace RT\AuthBundle\DependencyInjection\Vzaar;
use Exception;

class OAuthException extends Exception {
  // pass
}

class OAuthConsumer {
     //some code
}

class OAuthToken {
     //some code
}

?>
```

I am inheriting above file in Vzaar.php file which is with in same namespace and it's code is as below

```
    <?php
    namespace RT\AuthBundle\DependencyInjection\Vzaar;

    /*require_once 'OAuth.php';
    require_once 'HttpRequest.php';
    require_once 'AccountType.php';
    require_once 'User.php';
    require_once 'VideoDetails.php';
    require_once 'VideoList.php';
    require_once 'UploadSignature.php';*/

    use RT\AuthBundle\DependencyInjection\Vzaar\OAuth;
    use RT\AuthBundle\DependencyInjection\Vzaar\HttpRequest;
    use RT\AuthBundle\DependencyInjection\Vzaar\AccountType;
    use RT\AuthBundle\DependencyInjection\Vzaar\User;
    use RT\AuthBundle\DependencyInjection\Vzaar\VideoDetails;
    use RT\AuthBundle\DependencyInjection\Vzaar\VideoList;
    use RT\AuthBundle\DependencyInjection\Vzaar\UploadSignature;
    //use RT\AuthBundle\DependencyInjection\Vzaar\OAuth\OAuthConsumer;

    Class Profile
    {
       public static function setAuth($_url, $_method = 'GET')
       {
        $consumer = new OAuthConsumer('', '');
            //some code
       }
    }
?>
```

Creating new object of OAuthConsumer class throws error that

```
Fatal error:  Class 'RT\AuthBundle\DependencyInjection\Vzaar\OAuthConsumer' not found in /var/temp/rt-web/src/RT/AuthBundle/DependencyInjection/Vzaar/Vzaar.php

1/1 ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "OAuthConsumer" from namespace "RT\AuthBundle\DependencyInjection\Vzaar" in /var/temp/rt-web/src/RT/AuthBundle/DependencyInjection/Vzaar/Vzaar.php line 378. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
```

Comment: Why do you have classes other than `OAuth` in `OAuth.php`? Symfony is looking for `OAuthConsumer` in `OAuthConsumer.php`

Comment: @FuzzyTree I know about this, but I want to know is there any way we can achieve this ?? and this are pre defined classes, I have n't created

Comment: Isn't `require_once 'OAuth.php'` working?

Comment: A comment from [PHP : namespaces.importing](http://in1.php.net/namespaces.importing#114265) *The <?php use ?> statement does not load the class file. You have to do this with the <?php require ?> statement or by using an autoload function.*

Comment: @Log1cツ Symfony treats last name as file name. i.e. `use RT\AuthBundle\ExternalClass\SimpleImage;` then there must be SimpleImage.php file inside folder **ExternalClass**, I want to inherit class with in **SimpleImage** Class, In core php it is working, but noy in symfony, I am hoping there might be some way to do same in Symfony as well...

Comment: not sure, may be [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/class_extension.html) helps.

Comment: It didn't address the goal @Log1cツ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because since 2.1 Symfony uses composer, and composer uses PSR-0/PSR-4 to autoloading the classes, you have to follow the namespace convention, so you have to create those classes in separate files and in the right directory structure, what is represented in the namespace.

**EDIT**

As Cerad mentioned in the comment, you can specify a class map in composer, **although** what is considered as a best practice with symfony projects, create every class in a separate file.

Comment: Started creating separate classes, though its a big headache :(

Comment: Composer also supports class maps for loading classes that do not confirm to the regular naming conventions.  https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload.  Down voting this answer because it is simply incorrect.

Comment: You are correct, composer support that, I will edit my answer

Comment: No more down vote!  And while creating one file per class is recommended it's not always possible or practical when dealing with existing code.  Especially 3rd party stuff.